# Windows programs crashing after Windows 10 v1709 upgrade

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, crash, windows-10-v1709

After upgrading to Windows 10 v1709, I have been getting errors regarding Windows programs. Windows Explorer, Microsoft Management Console, and Snipping Tool have all had "stopped responding" issues. Here are the 2 logged errors I get from the Snipping Tool crash:

1st error (.NET Runtime):

```
Application: SnippingTool.exe
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: exception code c0000005, exception address 00007FF865B8AFC1
```

2nd error (Application Error):

```
Faulting application name: SnippingTool.exe, version: 10.0.16299.15, time stamp: 0xafccc4c1
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.16299.248, time stamp: 0xeffc9126
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000004afc1
Faulting process id: 0x2fa4
Faulting application start time: 0x01d3ddad27c82a79
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\system32\SnippingTool.exe
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 1aabb947-4440-4c69-8ca6-1e2b63e90044
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

From Windows Explorer crashing:

1st error (.NET Runtime):

```
Application: Explorer.EXE
Framework Version: v4.0.30319
Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: exception code c0000005, exception address 00007FF865B8BFDA
```

2nd error (Application Error):

```
Faulting application name: Explorer.EXE, version: 10.0.16299.248, time stamp: 0x18ee648b
Faulting module name: ntdll.dll, version: 10.0.16299.248, time stamp: 0xeffc9126
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x000000000004bfda
Faulting process id: 0x830
Faulting application start time: 0x01d3dd73e9a65da2
Faulting application path: C:\WINDOWS\Explorer.EXE
Faulting module path: C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
Report Id: 808edb11-ec12-45b7-836e-f59e3af2a49c
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

Looking at these logs, the same component (DLL) failed in both cases, which is C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll, part of Microsoft .NET Framework.

These crashes most often happen when I minimize the windows and then attempt to restore them.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Based on those outputs your build is at least 3 months old.  If File Explorer is crashing it’s time to revert the upgrade.

Comment: Verify these programs still crash while in Safe Mode.  Edit your question with the results of that the test

Answer (score 0):

Try to use clean boot to boot PC into a clean environment to see it the issue still occur.

Here is a link:How to perform a clean boot in Windows:
https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/929135/how-to-perform-a-clean-boot-in-windows

Try to run DISM /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth command  in Command Prompt (as administrator) to check system files and recovery corrupted files.

Check if the PC is up to date.